# wrong output when decoding base64 string

Tags: vb.net, base64

i seem to always get incorrect output when decoding this base64 string in vb.net ( i think its base64? it really looks like it )

im using the frombase64string function

and i did it like this

```
  Dim b64str = "0DDQQL3uAikQBgAAc4cqK4WnSQBg4SAgExEAAF3BAmAILYojRgkBhUrBAgEDRw=="
        Dim i As String = System.Text.Encoding.Unicode.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(b64str))
        MsgBox(i)
```

but i always get this output

```
バ䃐⤂ؐ
```

that doesn't seem right

Comment: We cannot be sure *what* you expect it to be. Have you compared it to the non-base64 source, or have you tried using online converters to check your results? The `FromBase64String` function is working just fine - if you are getting the wrong data then you either are using the wrong encoding, or have a faulty base64 string.

Comment: ***What is is supposed to look like?***

Comment: You have to know what the source was that created it.  It may have been the resulting byte array from a encryption method in which case decoding it wont result in anything useful.

Comment: When the string is Base64 decoded there are to many patterns for it to be any real encryption.

Answer (score 1):

> 0DDQQL3uAikQBgAAc4cqK4WnSQBg4SAgExEAAF3BAmAILYojRgkBhUrBAgEDRw==

It looks like Base64, the length is a correct size, the characters belong to the Base64 character set and the trailing "==" is reasonable. Of course it might not be a Base64 encoding.

Base64 decoding results in:

> D0 30 D0 40 BD EE 02 29 10 06 00 00 73 87 2A 2B 85 A7 49 00 60 E1 20 20 13 11 00 00 5D C1 02 60 08 2D 8A 23 46 09 01 85 4A C1 02 01 03 47

Now the problem, this is not a character string, it is an array of 8-bit bytes. Thus it can not be displayed as characters. The 0x00 bytes will signal the end of a string to the print method and the no-representable characters may be ignored, displayed with special characters or multiple bytes may display as must-byte unicode characters. The only guaranteed and usual display is in hexadecimal as above.

Answer (score 0):

That `String` can be virtually anything. It might be the result of an encryption algorithm, like sha*. Your mistake is that you assume that it *must* be base64 because it *might* be.

It is a valid observation that it might be base64, so it was a perfectly valid thing to run that function, but it is you who has to determine whether based on the results it is base64 or something else, based on particular logic, which was not described in the question.